# Shared working dir with git

Tags: git

Is it possible multiple developers to share same working dir (git) to change code and commit their changes. For example every developer can use its own .git folder... export GIT_DIR=.git_${SUDO_USER}

I know it is against all what git stood for and probably redesign of the dev process/env is required. Currently this is due to mutli-gigabytes setup, that cannot be replicated for each developer. There are already 200 instances, which are differentiated by the infrastructure and branch (code version). If developers appear as a factor in the equation, it makes 200 instance * 300 developers * 200 GB per instance - a big number.
On demand cloning is also no go, due to infrastructure requirements.

Currently it is CVS with edit/unedit, which allow this kind of interactions, but we are looking to change it with git.

Comment: Why is your code repository over 200GB? Are there large non-code artifacts of some sort there? Have you considered using something like [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to reduce the amount of data in the repository?

Comment: Git is not CVS.

Comment: Make a depot on a shared filesystem containing static history that will not change, and do your clones `--reference=/path/to/that/repo`.

Comment: it is not the code repository, that is 200GB, but the final system setup and currently it is required, fully setup in order to test anything, even compiling is linking some of the infrastructure libs.

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with git.

Comment: I'm not sure "nothing" is appropriate here. Code is part of this 200GB setup. Without the code - the setup is incomplete and without the setup - code cannot be compiled. Both are interconnected.